# JS: Capitalize first letter of every word entered into input

Tags: javascript, join, split

The below html & javascript needs to take the text entered into the input field and capitalize the first letter of every word upon hitting submit.  It's not working properly and I'm wondering where I've gone wrong?

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var words;
    words = str.split(" "); 
    for (var i=0 ; i < words.length ; i++){ 
      var testwd = words[i]; 
      var firLet = testwd.substr(0,1); 
      var rest = testwd.substr(1, testwd.length -1) 
      words[i] = firLet.toUpperCase() + rest 
     } 
   document.write( words.join("demo")); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Book Title</p>

<input id="words" value="18" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for a pure Javascript solution.

Comment: Where do you specify the value of `str` in `myFunction()` function?

Comment: Not sure, I am lost currently.  Appreciate any guidance, as I'm trying to grab the user input text via id words and var words.  When I just have words.split(" "); console tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! Keep going.

First - to get the value from the textbox with native Javascript you would need to use

```
document.getElementById("words").value;
```

which you should set to the `words` variable. I didn't see what `str` was being used for, but really you can just replace it with `words` at the `str.split(" ");`

Here is the full example with working code:
(Keep in mind that with document.write() you are writing over the entire page... and usually people just insert values into other places, so you can still maintain the page while showing them dynamic output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var words = document.getElementById('words').value;
    words = words.split(" "); 
    for (var i=0 ; i < words.length ; i++){ 
      var testwd = words[i]; 
      var firLet = testwd.substr(0,1); 
      var rest   = testwd.substr(1, testwd.length -1) 
      words[i]   = firLet.toUpperCase() + rest 
     } 
   document.write( words.join("demo")); 
}
</script>
<p>Book Title</p>

<input id="words" value="18" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `var words;` with `var words = document.getElementById("words");`

//Just a quick help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
 function myFunction(){
            var words = document.getElementById("words").value.split(" ");
            var content = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                content += words[i].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1, words[i].length - 1);
                if(i<words.length-1)
                    content += " ";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerText = content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('target').value = document.getElementById('target').value.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
};
```

```html
<input id="target" />
<button id="do" onclick="myFunction()">Go!</button>
```

### How this works

So first we detect when the button is clicked. Then we set the value to its original value but... We get the first letter in a word, then capitalize it.

As simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to pass every splitted word in your for loop and concatinate again with " ":

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Check Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7gceumz/